# pure Poisson birth process ordinary differential equations

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, poisson-process

Consider the pure Poisson process defined by
\begin{align}
P_n'(t) &= -\lambda_n P_n(t) + \lambda_{n-1}P_{n-1}, \quad n \geq 1,\\
P'_0(t) &= -\lambda_0 P_0(t).
\end{align}

with $P_0(0) = 1$. Let $\lambda_n > 0$ for all $n$, prove that for every fixed $n \geq 1$, the function $P_n(t)$ first increases, then decreases to $0$. If $t_n$ is the place of the maximum, then $t_1 < t_2< t_3<\dots$

The hint suggests to use induction and differentiate these set of equations, but I'm not sure how that gives arise to the answer.

Comment: Your solution doesn't have $P_1(0)=0$ as you'd assumed.

Comment: That was a typo, it should be $P_1(0) = 1$ but your point still stands

Comment: There should be a minus sign before $λ_n$? You could try $P_n(t)=\sum_{k=0}^n c_ke^{-λ_kt}$.

Comment: @Math_Day $P_1(0) = 1$ or $P_0(0) = 1$?

Comment: Did you try to carry out the solution and its analysis for $n=1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: If $\ \lambda_nP_n(0)>\lambda_{n-1}P_{n-1}(0)\ $ then $\ P_n'(0)=$$\,-\lambda_nP_n(0)+\lambda_{n-1}P_{n-1}(0)<0\ $, and it could not be true that $\ P_n(t)\ $ "first increases".  Are there some missing conditions on $\ \lambda_n\ $ and $\ P_n(0)\ $ which would guarantee that $\ \lambda_nP_n(0)\le\lambda_{n-1}P_{n-1}(0)\ $?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera No need for some conditions on the parameters. The initial condition is such that the states will first increase and then decrease to zero. This is quite intuitive in that case.

Comment: @KBS It looks like I might have fundamentally misunderstood the question, since I don't understand your reply.  I won't pursue the matter, however, since it would be inappropriate for me to clutter up the comments by doing so.

Comment: There is no initial condition for $P_n$ when $n \ge 1$. Do you want to assume $P_n(0)=0$ or $P_n(0)=1$?

Comment: I'm uncertain but I think it should be $P_n(0) = 1$.

Comment: Assuming I *haven't* actually misunderstood the question, then I believe I may be able to  prove the result if there are  initial conditions requiring $\ P_n(0)=0\ $ ( but not if they require $\ P_n(0)=1\ $).

Comment: @lonzaleggiera The initial condition is $P_0(0)=1$ and $P_n(0)=0$ for $n\ge1$. This is a continuous-time Markov chain so the sum of the initial conditions over $n$ should be equal to 1.

Comment: @KBS Thank you. I was mistaken in believing I understood what was going on, but I think I do so now.  The Poisson point process is an increasing sequence of times $\ T_0,$$\,T_0+T_1,\dots,$$\,\sum_\limits{i=0}^nT_i, \dots\ $, where $\ T_i\ $ are independent random variables with $\ T_i\sim\text{Exp}\big(\lambda_1\big)\ $. The pdf of $\ \sum_\limits{i=0}^nT_i\ $ is $\ \lambda_nP_n\ $, and the condition $\ P_n(0)=0\ $ for $\ n\ge1\ $ is needed to ensure that this is the case.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Here the random variables $T_0$, $T_0+T_1$,... all follow a hypoexponential distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoexponential_distribution) and we have that $P_n(t)=\mathbb{P}(X(t)=n|X(0)=0)$ where $X(t)$ is the random variable describing described by the Poisson process defined as $X:[0,\infty)\mapsto\{0,1,\ldots\}$. That is it starts at state $0$, then jumps to state $1$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from the differential equation and initial condition for $\ P_0\ $ that $\ P_0(t)=e^{-\lambda_0t}\ $. Thus, $\ \lambda_0P_0\ $ is the density of an exponential distribution with parameter $\ \lambda_0\ $.

From the differential equation and initial condition for $\ P_n\ $ for $\ n\ge1\ $ (namely, $\ P_n(0)=0\ $), we get
\begin{align}
P_n(t)&=\lambda_{n-1}e^{-\lambda_nt}\int_0^te^{\lambda_ns}P_{n-1}(s)ds\\
&=\int_0^te^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}\lambda_{n-1}P_{n-1}(s)ds\\
&=\int_0^te^{-\lambda_n\sigma}\lambda_{n-1}P_{n-1}(t-\sigma)d\sigma
\end{align}
Thus, if $\ \lambda_{n-1}P_{n-1}\ $ is a probability density function, then $\ \lambda_nP_n\ $ is the convolution of this density function with that of an exponential distribution with parameter $\ \lambda_n\ $, and is hence also a probability density function—namely that of the sum of two independent random variables $\ T_n\sim\text{Exp}\big(\lambda_n\big)\ $ and $\ X_n\sim\lambda_{n-1}P_{n-1}\ $.  Since $\ \lambda_0P_0 $ is the density function of a random variable $\ T_0\sim\text{Exp}\big(\lambda_0\big)\ $, it follows by induction that $\ \lambda_nP_n\ $ is the probability density function of a sum
$$
\sum_{i=0}^nT_i
$$
of independent random variables $\ T_0,T_1,\dots, T_n\ $ with $\ T_i\sim\text{Exp}\big(\lambda_i\big)\ $, and hence that $\ \lim_\limits{t\rightarrow\infty}P_n(t)=0\ $.

Evaluating the above integral for $\ P_1\ $ gives
$$
P_1(t)=\cases{\frac{\lambda_0\big(e^{-\lambda_1t}-e^{-\lambda_0t}\big)}{\lambda_0-\lambda_1}&if $\ \lambda_1\ne\lambda_0\ $,\\
\lambda_0t e^{-\lambda_0t} &if $\ \lambda_1=\lambda_0\ $.}
$$
In the first case, $\ P_1(t)\ $ is strictly increasing for $\ 0<t<t_1=\frac{\ln\lambda_0-\ln\lambda_1}{\lambda_0-\lambda_1}\ $, reaches a maximum at $\ t=t_1\ $ and is strictly decreasing for $\ t>t_1\ $.  In the second case, $\ P_1(t)\ $ is strictly increasing for $\ 0<t<t_1'=\frac{1}{\lambda_0}\ $, reaches a maximum at $\ t=t_1'\ $ and is strictly decreasing for $\ t>t_1'\ $.

Suppose now that $\ n\ge2\ $ and $\ P_{n-1}(t)\ $ is strictly increasing for $\ 0<t<t_{n-1}\ $, reaches a maximum at $\ t=t_{n-1}\ $, and is strictly decreasing for $\ t>t_{n-1}\ $. Differentiating the last of the integral expressions above for $\ P_n(t)\ $ gives
\begin{align}
P_n'(t)&= \lambda_{n-1}\int_0^t e^{-\lambda_n\sigma}P_{n-1}'(t-\sigma)d\sigma+\lambda_{n-1} e^{-\lambda_nt}P_{n-1}(0)\\
&=\lambda_{n-1}\int_0^t e^{-\lambda_n\sigma}P_{n-1}'(t-\sigma)d\sigma\\
&=\lambda_{n-1}\int_0^t e^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}P_{n-1}'(s)ds\ .
\end{align}
For $\ t<t_{n-1}\ $, the integrand of this last integral is strictly positive over the interval $\ [0,t]\ $, and hence so is the integral itself.  That is, $\ P_n'(t)>0\ $ for $\ t<t_{n-1}\ $, and so $\ P_n(t)\ $ is strictly increasing over the interval $\ \big[0,t_{n-1}\big]\ $.
Since $\ P_n\ $ is continuously differentiable for $\ t>0\ $, and $\ \lim_\limits{t\rightarrow\infty}P_n(t)=0\ $, there must exist a point at which $\ P_n(t)\ $ reaches a maximum and $\ P_n'(t)\ $ vanishes. Let
$$
t_n=\inf\big\{\,t\,\big|\,t>0\ \&\ P_n'(t)=0\,\big\}\ .
$$
Then $\ t_n>t_{n-1}\ $, and at that point, we have
$$
P_n'(t_n)=0= \lambda_{n-1}\int_0^{t_n} e^{-\lambda_n(t_n-s)}P_{n-1}'(s)ds\ ,
$$
and $\ P_n\ $ must be strictly increasing over the interval $\ \big[0,t_n\big]\ $.
For $\ t>t_n\ $, we have

\begin{align}
P_n'(t)&=\lambda_{n-1}\int_0^te^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}P_{n-1}'(s)ds\\
&=\lambda_{n-1}\left(\int_0^{t_n}e^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}P_{n-1}'(s)ds+\int_{t_n}^te^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}P_{n-1}'(s)ds\right)\\
&=\lambda_{n-1}\left(e^{\lambda(t_n-t)}\int_0^{t_n}e^{-\lambda_n(t_n-s)}P_{n-1}'(s)ds+\int_{t_n}^te^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}P_{n-1}'(s)ds\right)\\
&=\lambda_{n-1}\int_{t_n}^te^{-\lambda_n(t-s)}P_{n-1}'(s)ds\\
&<0\ ,
\end{align}
because the integrand of the final integral is strictly negative over the interval $\ \big[t_n,t\big]\ $. It follows that $\ P_n(t)\ $ is strictly decreasing for $\ t>t_n\ $.  This completes the proof that $\ P_n(t)\ $ is strictly increasing over an interval $\ \big[0,t_n\big]\ $, with  $\ t_n>t_{n-1}\ $, strictly decreasing for $\ t>t_n\ $, and $\ \lim_\limits{t\rightarrow\infty}P_n(t)=0\ $. It follows by induction that these properties hold for all $\ n\ge1\ $.